# AndroidObservable never observing on the main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java

I'm experimenting with [RxJava for Android](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava). I'm trying a simple example, where i'm trying to offload a longer operation on a background thread, and then expecting to come back on the main thread and do a ui operation.

I get the search text from an `EditText` `onTextChangeListener` (by way of a nifty ButterKnife injection), then shoot that out to a long running operation `_searchForContacts(searchText)` that returns a list of Contact objects. I then go on to update my view by setting the info on my adapter and notifying a dataset change.

However, I run into an exception when trying to do any ui updates, because i'm never on the main thread.

Here's my code:

```
public class MyTestFragment
    extends Fragment
    implements Observer<List<Contact>> {

    // ...

    private Subscription _searchGuestsSubscription = Subscriptions.empty();

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        _searchGuestsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        _adapter = new ContactImportAdapter();
        _adapter.setContacts(_searchForContacts(ALL_CONTACTS));
        _listView.setAdapter(_adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(List<Contact> contactSearchResults) {
        Timber.d("I'm on the main thread -> " + String.valueOf(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()));
        _adapter.setContacts(contactSearchResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        _updateView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Timber.e(e, "Oops something went wrong.");
    }

    // ButterKnife ~ onTextChangeListener
    @OnTextChanged(R.id.search_edit_text)
    void onSearchContact(CharSequence searchChars) {
        _searchGuestsSubscription = AndroidObservable.bindFragment(this,
                                                                   _searchGuestsObservable(searchChars.toString()))
                                                     // The below line doesn't seem to have any effect?
                                                     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                                     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                                     .subscribe(this);
    }

    private Observable<List<Contact>> _searchGuestsObservable(final String searchText) {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Contact>>() {


            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super List<Contact>> searchResultObserver) {
                // do the search
                List<Contact> contactSearchResults = _searchForContacts(searchText);
                onNext(contactSearchResults);
                onCompleted();
            }
        });
    }

    private void _updateView() {
        _adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

It says that `onNext` is always called on a background thread. I get the usual `IllegalStateException: The current thread must have a looper!` exception. The log statements also indicate that i'm not on the main thread within `onNext`.

What gives?

Comment: Try to run on another thread

Comment: do you mean try to run on a thread other than the .io thread? I actually also tried `Schedulers.newThread()` but that didn't work. 

If i only stick to the main thread, then everything works, but I guess that would defeat the point, since i explicitly want to run the operation on a non-ui thread, and then callback into the ui thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be coming from the fact that you're calling the onNext in your Fragment directly instead of calling the onNext on the subscriber.

Change your code like so.

```
private Observable<List<Contact>> _searchGuestsObservable(final String searchText) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super List<Contact>> searchResultObserver) {
            // do the search
            List<Contact> contactSearchResults = _searchForContacts(searchText);
            searchResultObserver.onNext(contactSearchResults);
            searchResultObserver.onCompleted();
        }
    });
}
```

When your `Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Contact>>()` is executed your are in fact on the background thread by then because of the `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` and you're calling your Fragment's onNext yourself, that's why you get that Exception.

Comment: right you are! I like to blame the horrible syntax (courtesy Android not supporting Java 8 features) but truth is I simply didn't understand the call sequence correctly. Thanks for that, cheers!